# How to fix ProxyPass in URL and subfolder?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, proxypass

I made a proxy pass adding to my localhost instance the path /vocab/arch. Here the configuration I used:

```
        <IfModule mod_proxy.c>

                ProxyPass /vocab/arch http://localhost:3000/
                ProxyPassReverse /vocab/arch http://localhost:3000/
                Alias /vocab/arch /assets/
        </IfModule>

        <Location />
                Require all granted
        </Location>

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule  ^/vocab/arch   -  [L]
        RewriteRule  ^/(.*)    http://localhost:3000/$1  [P,L]
        ProxyPassReverse /vocab/arch     http://localhost:3000/
```

Pointing to http://localhost:3000/ I'm having the landing page of my web-app as expected under http://localhost:3000/vocab/arch/en.html.

However clicking on some link like "Collections" I'm having https://localhost:3000/en/collections.html instead of https://localhost:3000/vocab/arch/en/collections.html

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What vHost do these directives reside under? "Pointing to http://localhost:3000/ I'm having the landing page of my web-app as expected under http://localhost:3000/vocab/arch/en.html" - which part of your config is doing that? Your "collections" URL is using HTTPS - not HTTP (as you've seemingly defined above)?

Answer (score 0):

Fix your sub-host.  proxy-pass won't re-write responses coming from the other web-server.  So, if the other-server (on port 3000) gives hrefs and links to URLs without proper paths, you'll see exactly what you've got.

i.e. your localhost:3000 server is returning links to https://localhost:3000/en/collections.html instead of https://localhost:3000/vocab/arch/en/collections.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: I have no clue what your sub-host is running.  I would modify it so it works with the same paths that exist in the parent host.  i.e. /vocab/arch/  instead of just working from /en/